# how to add current user id to menu link in joomla

Tags: joomla, menu, hyperlink

I want to pass the user id as filter with menu link to select items from list of database object that belong to that user. How to add current user id to menu link. The xml file parmaters are static I think. They doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add the User ID to the menu link (and security wise it's probably a very bad idea). You can retrieve the User ID of the current user anywhere in Joomla!.

e.g. ( *you haven't specified your Joomla! version but for 2.5 you can get it this way* )

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$userId = $user->get('id');
```

Comment: ı have where statemen in my code if a request variable is not empty it is used to filter the query. I want to use same view model and controller to show list of both all item list and item list of current user in personal menu mpdule to see that user its items. So ı should send the user id as query varible in menu url. I think no code needed to describe this.

Comment: I did it like that. When that layout is opening if any id isn't set in the query the id will set as current user's